# Powershell function's default parameter does not work

Tags: powershell

I have a function in a module I created:

```
   function New-MyAppDeployment {
   param
   (
        [string]$ConfigPath = "C:\Projects\MyApp\Environments",
        [string]$EnvName,
        [string]$EnvironmentFile
   )
   # Do some things with the above parameters
   if(!$EnvironmentFile)
   {
       $envFilename = $EnvName + ".json";
       $EnvironmentFile = Join-Path $ConfigPath $envFilename

   }

   $settings = Get-Content -Raw -Path $EnvironmentFile | ConvertFrom-Json

   return $settings    
   }
   Export-ModuleMember -function New-MyAppDeployment
```

I then call it like this:
    Import-Module -Force $PSScriptRoot\myapp.psm1
       $newSettings = New-MyAppDeployment -EnvName "dev"

but `$ConfigPath` always is set to an empty string when I'm inside the function.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: the example above works fine for me, I'm not sure what `$settings` does thou

Comment: Same for me. Please provide a [mcve] if you want further help with this.

Comment: This works fine as per the script you wrote. But I am wondering what the settings does.

Comment: I assume $settings is just passed to the pipeline, using `return $settings` would be better.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your code snippet? 
`if($!EnvironmentFile)` should be `if( !$EnvironmentFile )`

Comment: Your newly updated code still doesn't demonstrate that `$ConfigPath` is empty. You have other errors in your code. Have you even run this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have corrected itself. Perhaps restarting the ISE did the trick, but now `$ConfigPath` has the correct value when stepping through the code.